# SpringBoot profiles with Gradle vs cloud

Tags: java, gradle, spring-cloud

I have some problem with starting microservice with cloud config on local machine:
In application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my_servie
  config:
    import: 'configserver:'
  profiles:
    group:
      env-prod-pg: postgres,log
```

I create application-local.yml, where add:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: mc-service-logistics-v2
  config:
    import: 'optional:configserver:'
```

and some other config updates,
in build.gradle I add:

```
tasks.register("bootRunLocal") {
    group = "application"
    description = "Runs the Spring Boot application with the local profile"
    doFirst {
        tasks.bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "local")
        }
    }
    finalizedBy("bootRun")
}
```

but when I try to start app with gradle bootRunLocal I caught error:
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/my-service/local": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

If I understand- application still want to use cloud config and can't start. If I comment
**spring.config.import**  in application.yml- aplication started without any problem.

How to solve this problem? I don't want to push to repo my local config again)

Comment: all spring config imports are executed. They are not overridden like normal configuration properties

Comment: @spencergibb well, how to run app on local machine in this case? I have no access to cloud

Comment: put all `spring.config.import` statements in an `application-<profile>.yml` file rather than in the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I create to application-.yml and application.yml ,where store current profile:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
```